# Spring - how to debug to find specific use of spring's auto-wiring or a request parameter?

Tags: spring

Spring is auto-wiring in a request parameter - let's call it "bob".

I don't know where nor how it is doing this, so I cannot debug it. What spring specific code (using intellij, so I can at lest set a conditional) would be appropriate to find where the auto-wiring of the request parameter is happening, so I can work out what the system is doing?

Comment: can you explain a bit more in detail ? are you saying you have a rest endpoint and its request parameter is autowiring to a bean based on it ? are you using @RequestParam ? can you post some your controller and url on how the request is made and what is being autowired.

Comment: hey @Jayesh, the RequestParam doesn't seem to be needed to auto-wire in request parameters in spring. It's just advised to use it - as a result, I don't know which ModelAttribue is auto-wiring (i mean, automagically taking a request parameter value and popping it in the right spot), so it's not like I have a particular ModelAttribute block to share.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer helped you in any way. I will try to improve it if it did not match your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understood the question, so I will try to answer it as best as I can.

You are facing a dilemma of choosing between managing your instances, or letting Spring manage them. If you let Spring manage dependency injection, you will often face situations where you wish you had more fine control over the beans [lifecycle](https://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-bean-life-cycle-tutorial).

> By default, Spring beans are "singletons", which means that only one
>   instance of that object will be created, and every class that demands
>   a dependency injection of that object will receive the same instance.

The first step on beans lifecycle is its construction. You can setup a breakpoint to catch that moment on any method annotated with `@PostConstruct`. This [article](https://medium.com/@dmarko484/spring-boot-startup-init-through-postconstruct-765b5a5c1d29) describes the need of running some code on bean initialization, and how it is solved by this annotation. For example:

```
public class AnyBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        // any code or breakpoints inserted here will
        // be run whenever an instance of this bean is created.
        // if a singleton bean, only one instance is created and, 
        // only one @PostConstruct will be called.


        // If a bean is a prototype bean, a new instance will be created
        // for every dependency injection, and hence one @PostConstruct 
        // will be called for each.
    }
}
```